How do display discarded messages when searching through elasticsearch?
I am using gem elasticsearch-rails to perform search for messages.However, it does not display the discarded message's record. I have tried using unscoped too, but that does not work either.
Ex: Message.unscoped.search('something')
How can i get it
I would like to receive soft deleted messages as well

What do you mean by discarded messages? Who discarded them? When you say "soft deleted messages", do you mean the soft deletion mechanism in Elasticsearch or this is something specific to your application?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sorry for not describing my problem clearly. Specifically it is as follows:
My messages table has a discarded_at column used to mark records that will be thrown away.
#Message
  include Discard::Model
default_scope -> { kept }
#Discard
scope:kept, ->{ where(discarded_at => nil) }
When I use Message.search('foobar').records, it seems to only retrieve messages with the discarded_at column set to null, which I need to include messages with the value discarded_at. I used Rails' unscoped, but it didn't work. Gem Discard: https://github.com/jhawthorn/discard
